# VBA .ClearContents for inserted Rows?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a code that finds three rows and insert the same rows below them, but I need to clear contents of these inserted rows, unfortunately, the selecetion applies for the first three rows and not those inserted.

```
    Sub Add_Timber()
'
' Add_Timber Macro
'

'
    Cells.Find(What:="Timber | Zakázky:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.EntireRow.Copy
    Selection.Offset(3, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown


    Cells.Find(What:="Timber | JIRA ID:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.EntireRow.Copy
    Selection.Offset(3, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown


    Cells.Find(What:="Timber | Hodiny:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.EntireRow.Copy
    Selection.Offset(3, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown


End Sub
```

[So in picture a red block is copied from the previous and I want to delete the data in the NEW INSERTED rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHjzv.png)

Comment: You should definitely read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba Why not just insert blank rows?

Comment: Because I need first column to copy.

Comment: you might add some screenshots to better describe your data layout and your goal

Comment: Thank you, added a screenshot with description.

Comment: are those three rows always *consecutive* and in the *same order* (first "Zakázky", then "JIRA" and then "Hodiny")?

Comment: Hello @HTH yes they are.

Answer (score 0):

Since rows are Always conscutive and in the same ordwer, then you could make copy/insert in one shot

```
Sub Add_Timber()

    Dim f As Range
    Set f = Cells.Find(What:="Timber | Zakázky:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)' try finding "Timber | Zakázky:"

    If Not f Is Nothing Then 'if succesfull
        With f.Resize(3).EntireRow ' reference found cell row along with its two consecutive ones
            .Offset(3).Insert ' insert referenced rows three rows below the referenced ones
            .Copy .Offset(3) ' copy referenced rows three rows below
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```